# Dynamically convert a JSON config into a Typescript Class

Tags: json, typescript, abstract

I have scoured the Net, I have read the typescript documents and looked at many answers here on stack overflow. None have given me enough insights on the following:

Using typescript I import a `JSON` file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "property" : "FristName",
        "type" : "string"
    },
    {
        "property" : "LastName",
        "type" : "string"
    },
    {
        "property" : "Age",
        "type" : "number"
    }
]
```

The `property` key is a `class property` and the `type` key denotes the `property type`.

Then I am attempting to write a class constructor that dynamically turns it at runtime into:

```
class Person {
    public FirstName: string;
    public LastName: string;
    public Age: number
{
```

The `JSON array` could potentially have an index of `n` object literals. The object literal structure is static and will always only have the two attributes `attribute` and `type`.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with "dynamic programming" and the tag should be removed (the tag description should make that clear)

Answer (score 1):

A good practice would be to create a `PersonFactory` class, with a public `fromJSON` method that accepts a JSON string and returns a Person instance.

```
import { Person } from "person";

export interface Spec {
  [index: number]: {attribute: string, type: "string" | string };
}

export class PersonFactory {
    fromJSON(spec: Spec): Person {
        return new Person(spec[0].attribute, spec[1].attribute);
    }
}
```

Use the factory as:

```
import { PersonFactory, Spec } from "factories";

const data: Spec = require("person_spec.json");

const person: Person = (new PersonFactory()).fromJSON(data);
```

Comment: Thank you that is uber helpful. May I ask you see the edit.

Comment: My answer supports `n` object litteral, even with TypeScript (I edited typings into my answer). You just need to account for these objects in the interface, and in your factory method. There is no automatic way to go from `JSON` ---> instance, you need to build the converter yourself based on the shape of your JSON

Comment: Thanks the object literal structure will always have the two attributes only.

Comment: Please check the solution, the `export class PersonFactory()` should not have parenthesis.

Comment: The solution above defines a procedure for an instance(s) of the Person class via a factory. The idea is to have a factory that dynamically produces a class. I want to start off with a JSON file as a config defining the attributes/properties and their types to be the input to a procedure yielding a class.